# Android Google Maps using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

Although I did everything it asks me to in the [developers site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2)

several times I can't get the map working anyhow.. I even tried to change computer and try again.  When I try to launch the app it says gmap has unfortunately stopped working

Here is my MainActivity.java:``

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private GoogleMap map;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

When I check the logcat it says that there is error in main xml file where the fragment starts. Could you help me please.

Comment: Are you trying on an emulator or a device? The emulator had issues with the v2 google maps a while ago and I do not know if that has been fixed over time.

Comment: Is your build path done right and is the  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" fragment actually available for your application?

Comment: I've done my path right checked my whole code many times to be sure. I'm using emulator though maybe that is the problem. I will try it on a tablet tomorrow and give feedback

Comment: well it is either that or a permission error, maybe your API key is not set up properly

Comment: in eclipse, under window/preferences -> android/build I chose my debug.keystore and copied SHA1 to code.google site to get my API key and paste in my AndroidManifest.xml inside <application>

Comment: and added all the permissions correctly I think bacause I checked like 20 times

Comment: I even implemented a working googlemap project into eclipse still I cant run the app, I guess its because of the emulator

Comment: Yap. Try it on the device later. That could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all required permissions/api-key in your applications manifest file!

If you already did that post the whole exception here.

Comment: 06-25 12:47:50.302: E/AndroidRuntime(592): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-25 12:47:50.302: E/AndroidRuntime(592): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ak52.gmap/com.ak52.gmap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: line #7 is where the <fragment starts in the activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0):

I hope you do close your RelativeLayout with `</RelativeLayout>`.

also, I used `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` instead of `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` but your way could be perfectly fine too.

In my onCreate i did

```
SupportMapFragment mf = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

I never called .getMap as you did, and it works. Worth a try I'd guess.